# Transaction expiration when deploying a program to solana-test-validator

Tags: solana, solana-cli

I am able to upload a program to a Testnet with 1.11.15 CLI which is a recommended version for Testnet, but unable to upload same program to a `solana-test-validator` v1.11.5.

```
$ solana --url localhost --commitment confirmed program deploy target/deploy/program.so

Error: Account allocation failed: unable to confirm transaction. 
This can happen in situations such as transaction expiration and insufficient
fee-payer funds
```

And I definitely have sufficient funds

```
solana --url localhost balance

500000000 SOL
```

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, this is a bug in 1.11.5, which I believe was introduced as part of the QUIC rollout, please use 1.11.4 instead.

Comment: nice to meet you here John, this is @kkonevets from github, thanks

Comment: Oh hey! Small world :-D